# Problems Deploying Django App in Azure with Docker, Gunicorn and Nginx

Tags: django, azure, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my Django's web app with Docker using gunicorn and Nginx in Azure but after following all the steps, the app crashed before showing anything.
This is my Docker-compose:

```
`version: '3.7'

services:
  django_gunicorn:
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django_gunicorn

volumes:
  static:`
```

This is Dockerfile for Django & Gunicorn

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN pip install --upgrade pip


COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./myfuture /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

This is the entrypoint

```
    python manage.py migrate --no-input
    python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
    
    DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=$SUPER_USER_PASSWORD python manage.py createsuperuser --username $SUPER_USER_NAME --email $SUPER_USER_EMAIL --noinput

gunicorn myfuture.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

This is the Dockerfile for Nginx

```
FROM nginx:1.22.0-alpine

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

This is the default.conf

```
upstream django {
    server django_gunicorn:8000;   
}

server{
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }
}
```

This is the log:

```
[2023-07-06 02:03:58 +0000] [27] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-07-06 02:03:58 +0000] [27] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (27)
[2023-07-06 02:03:58 +0000] [27] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-07-06 02:03:58 +0000] [28] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 28`
```

In localhost works perfect...

Comment: Hope this helps Django Application — [Gunicorn and Nginx](https://blog.devgenius.io/dockerizing-django-application-gunicorn-and-nginx-5a74b250198f#:~:text=A%20step-by-step%20tutorial%20on%20dockerizing%20a%20Django%20application,we%E2%80%99ll%20see%20how%20to%20deploy%20the%20project%20on)

Comment: Developed a sample using this [refer](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/)